# drupal 6 menu hierarchy management

Tags: drupal-6

I'm looking for a D6 module to manage menu hierarchy the way that Taxonomy Manager does. Don't want to do it in the node edit form and the core drag-and-drop method is cumbersome for large menus. If I could collapse sections of the menu so that an item can easily dragged to another part, that would do it as well as something like taxonomy manager.

Answer (score 0):

The module you're looking for is called [**Hierarchical Select**](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select). To be more precise you're interested in the sub-module 'Hierarchical Select Menu'. If you visit the page you'll see the following in the module's description:

> The Drupal 6 version integrates with:
>
> - Forum (Drupal core)
> - Menu (Drupal core)
> - Taxonomy (Drupal core)
> - Content Taxonomy
> - Views — in combination with Taxonomy, not with Content Taxonomy
> - Node Reference (CCK)
> - User Terms
> - Hierarchical Select Field Selector
> - OG Subgroups

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I want to adjust the entire hierarchy of a single menu in one page. The best answer I've found so far is Big Menu. It provides a version of the menu admin page like Drupal core, but also lets you collapse/hide lower levels, or bring up a page with a subset of the menu.